# Changing permissions on a drive owned by root

Tags: hard-drive, permissions

Just installed 12.04, then formatted an external 2 Tb drive for use.  My next step would usually been to have logged in as root, changed the permissions to my admin user, then logged back out. . . but as many have bemoaned that can't be done anymore.

I'm not very familiar with the terminal and am looking for a new method that is as no muss no fuss as it was under 11.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In terminal log in to root:

```
sudo bash.
```

Then, change the permission on the drive it self should be permanent. Worked for me for a similar problem.

```
chown -R <username> <location>
```

Comment: worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

In terminal:

```
sudo passwd root

sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Log out. Log in as the user named 'login' with the password 'root'.
You will be showing as a Guest. Just ignore, You have root!

Comment: Sigh...I was hoping to give back by getting an answer accepted. This site has helped a lot and I didn't want to make it seem like I was just taking.

Answer (score 0):

Your hard-drive might be using NTFS, The NTFS filesystem does not support Linux permissions so you cannot change ownership of files, folders or the whole drive by chmodding.

When an NTFS partition is mounted using the ntfs-3g driver, all files and folders appear to be owned by root but ordinary users (on the host machine) can access all files read-write. [source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1450081)