# How to change a drive's permissions if it's owned by root?

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, root, format, read-only

Earlier I was trying to install steam on my 32 Gb Flash Drive, because my hard drive is very small, but I couldn't because it was FAT formatted. So then I formatted it to EXT 4 using GParted, and when I did that and went to install steam again, the drive was read only, and upon going to change it, it was owned by root.

There is already a question like this here-

### [Changing permissions on a drive owned by root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176817/changing-permissions-on-a-drive-owned-by-root)

but the solution there is to create a root user, however that involves logging out which I cannot do since my version of Ubuntu (xfce precise) is running side by side (dual booted) on a Chromebook (hence the low hard drive space), which means that If I log out, It closes the Ubuntu interface. So my question is this, how do I turn off read only if it is owned by root, without creating a new user?

Comment: Do you have sudo privileges?

Comment: I do have sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however that involves logging out

It doesn't necessarily involve a logout. You can create a *nested* terminal session as the root user that you create (or any other user, for that).

`su - username`

Will log you in as `username`. In fact, to login as root, you don't need to specify the username:

```
su -
```

Hope that helps.